# Redirect page to 410 if match a specific Regex in .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, regex

First time using .htaccess so I come here to have a bit of help since the web is not that file with informations (or I just don't find them :/).

So the idea is that I want to redirect link ending by `/2/` or  `/3/` ... (number) to the `error410` page.

So I came up with this regex which is working well `^(.*?)\/(?!(?:404|410)$)\d+$`

[Test Here](https://regex101.com/r/tD2sX0/5)

And if I get how this is working this is the right solution :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)\/(?!(?:404|410)$)\d+$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [G]
```

Do you think this will work or not ? I don't want to play the apprentice wizard..

Comment: in fact it do lot of things, you should use RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /[0-9]+/$ cause your request work ending by number but not ending by number + slash. Do you have to not redirect /404/ and /410/ request too ?

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. You are testing for the pattern against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. This variable does not store the URI content, but instead the query parameters as sent by `GET` or `POST`.

To send the **`GONE`** status, use the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\d+/?$ - [G]
```